# BufferedImage does not keep transparency when HSB values for an images is changed

Tags: java, image, transparency, bufferedimage, hsb

I'm working on a simple image program where the user can alter the HSB values of an image. However, when I change the HSB values of an images and convert back to RGB, it seems to lose it's transparency or alpha values (it goes black where the transparency is). Here's what I have below (I've put the relevant parts together):

```
public static BufferedImage getEnhancedImagesHSB(BufferedImage image, float[] hsbOrg)
{

  int height = image.getHeight();
  int width = image.getWidth();

  float[] hsb = new float[]{0,0,0,0};
  int[] originalPixels = image.getRGB(0,0, width, height, null, 0, width);
  int[] enhancedImagePixels = image.getRGB(0,0, width, height, null, 0, width);

  for (int i = 0; i < originalPixels.length; i++)
  {
    Color c = new Color( originalPixels[i]);
    int red =c.getRed();
    int green = c.getGreen();
    int blue = c.getBlue();

    hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(red, green, blue, hsb);

    hsb[ 3 ] = c.getAlpha() / 255f;

     hsb[0] = (float)(hsb[0] +( hsbOrg[0]/360.0));//hue

    hsb[1] *=  (hsbOrg[1]/100);
      if(hsb[1] > 1.0)
          hsb[1] = (float)0.9;


    hsb[2] *=  (hsbOrg[2]/100);
      if(hsb[2] > 1.0) 
          {hsb[2] = (float)0.9;}

    enhancedImagePixels[i] = Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb[0], hsb[1], hsb[2]);
  }


  BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB  );  
  newImage.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, enhancedImagePixels, 0, width);

  return newImage;
}
```

According to the docs getRGB(), setRGB() use the default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB) so the alpha values should be preserved. But changing the images HSB values results in the new buffered image having a black color where the transparency should be. How can I edit the images HSB values and then create a new image without losing the images transparency?

Edit:
Below is an image from before and after some random Hue, saturation and brightness has been applied. As you can see, the image has lost its transparency. 
[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Generate the image in code or hot-link to it.  Also, given that mess of words and symbols contains no '?' prompts me to ask.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Have a look at the edits I've made, let me know if you need more info. I'm trying to preserve the images transparency, but I get blacks instead where alpha values should be.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Color c2 = Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb[0], hsb[1], hsb[2]);
enhancedImagePixels[i] = new Color(c2.getRed(), c2.getGreen(), c2.getBlue(),
        c.getAlpha());
```

Which is ugly. There seems to be no conversion for hsb[3] (alpha).
Using a `image.getAlphaRaster()` might be the solution.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't known about getAlphaRaster() and rasters in Java. I'll give this a go and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Joop Eggen for pointing me into the right direction. I wrote directly into the image raster (using setPixel()) the adjusted Hue, saturation, brightness and alpha values. Below is a great article discussing the subject matter.

[Article.](http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6520-howto-chromakey.jsp)

Comment: Great; thanks for sharing your further research. I had a (temporary?) problem with the Article link though.